# question about epsilon, delta limit definition

Tags: calculus, limits, notation, definition

Sometimes, when describing the closeness of $x$ to $a$ as being less than $\delta$, it's stated as $|x-a|<\delta$ and sometimes it's stated as $0<|x-a|<\delta$.
What is the " $0<$ " part that's sometimes included in the definition, I'm a bit confused about that. Is it just telling us that the distance can't be zero? 
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "$0 <$" part explicates the interest in a *neighborhood* around a point. For any desired error, there exists a nonzero deviation from the point of interest such that the function evaluated inside this neighborhood does not change by more than the desired error.

Comment: A "deleted neighborhood"

Comment: Its a fancy way to say $x\neq a$. :)

Comment: Geometrically one can think of $|x-a|<\delta$ as a circle centred at $a$ with radius $\delta$ and $0<|x-a|<\delta$ as a half circle.

Comment: No, it is not a "half circle". It is a punctured disk. The terminology "half circle" obfuscates the point, and might confuse someone into thinking it is a semi-circle...